# Get Error during handling the Response in post web service

Tags: android, memory, virtual

I am calling the web service to draw point on the map. i found the 750 record in the response. while the page load second time it shows me this error.

FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-26
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.lang.String.(String.java:513)
    at org.apache.http.util.CharArrayBuffer.toString(CharArrayBuffer.java:261)
    at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:146)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:59)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:657)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
    at com.roundmenu.Nearme.run(Nearme.java:583)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        HttpGet post = null;

        Log.e("", "Share.isfromfilter =  " + Share.isfromfilter);
        if (Share.isfromfilter) {

            Log.e("", "Teset 1");

            Log.e("", "Share.CuisineValue =  " + Share.CuisineValue);

            if (Share.CuisineValue.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                Log.e("", "Teset 2");
                post = new HttpGet("my url here");
            } else {
                Log.e("", "Teset 3");
                post = new HttpGet("my url here");
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("", "Teset 4");
            post = new HttpGet("my url here");

        }
        post.addHeader("apikey", "880639B3638597349AC1BE6F70FC5682");
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

        response = client.execute(post, responseHandler);
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(response);

        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
    }
}
```

I am also get the VM Out of Budget Error during the executing this code.

Answer (score 0):

Android Dalvik VM has heap limitation. Could you tell how many bytes returned by the web service?
If the data size is huge, it's recommended to incrementally read the data instead of transferring all into one large string buffer.

Please refer to http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

if (entity != null) {
  InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
  try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
             new InputStreamReader(instream));
    String data = null;
    while ((data = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting 23000 bytes of data in my response

Comment: It's hard to tell and identify the root cause base on the backtrace of callstack. You could try DDMS to inspect your heap/ram usage in your App.